# Does $\mathbb{N} \cap \mathbb{N}^2 = \varnothing$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*Definitions.* A cardinal $\mathfrak{a}$ is said to be *finite* if $\mathfrak{a} \ne \mathfrak{a} + 1$. A finite cardinal is also called a *natural integer*. The natural integers form a set, denoted by $\mathbb{N}$. The set $\mathbb{N}^2$ is the Cartesian product of $\mathbb{N}$ with itself. In other words, $\mathbb{N}^2$ is the set of ordered pairs 
$$(m,n) = \bigl\{\{m\},\{m,n\}\bigr\}$$
where $m$ and $n$ are natural integers.

Comment: Define $\mathbb N^2$.

Comment: Are you defining $\mathbb{N}^2$ as a collection of (some encoding of) two element tuples?  Are you defining $\mathbb{N}$ as a collection of (some kind of) tuples?

Comment: @lulu That was originally a different question. I changed to this question after it had been downvoted.

Comment: Everyone: He said he's taking $\Bbb N$ to be the collection of finite cardinals. Then $\Bbb N^2=\{(n,mm):n,mm\in\Bbb N\}$, where he's presumably using the standard (Kuratowski) definition of $(n,m)$.

Comment: I can't see why this question is being downvoted.

Comment: @lulu  It seems like a valid question.  Why did you downvote it?

Comment: @NicNic8  I did not downvote it.

Comment: @simplejack No, that axiom does _not_ implicitly define ordered pairs.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich See edit. Sorry for the confusion. That is how ordered pairs were defined in my book.

Comment: @simplejack If that axiom is all you're given about ordered pairs II doubt that it's possible to prove this.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't think you saw my edit. Please do not worry about the axiom and use the standard definition of ordered pairs.

Comment: @simplejack No, his post shows that the answer depends on the definition of $(a,b)$, and hence that that axiom is not sufficient. You asked whether it depends on the definnition of $\Bbb N$; I don't see anything about that in his answer...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That's true.

Comment: You'd also need to define what a "cardinal" is. With the usual ZFC definition of cardinals as initial Von Neumann ordinals, @Wood's answer applies. But if, for example, you're using [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick) to represent cardinals, then you'll need a different argument.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I prefer the definition using Scott's trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments you say you're defining cardinals using [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick) -- that is, a cardinal is the set of all sets with a certain cardinality *of minimal rank*.

Then suppose there's a Kuratowski pair $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ that is also a cardinal. If $a\ne b$ then $\{a\}$ and $\{a,b\}$ have *different* cardinalities, so they're not elements of the same cardinal. Therefore $a=b$ and our pair has the form $\{\{a\}\}$. Since the element $\{a\}$ has one element, we must be looking at the number $1$ if we're looking at a cardinal at all.

The smallest-rank singleton is $\{\varnothing\}$, and there are no other singletons that has this rank. So under Scott's trick, $1=\{\{\varnothing\}\}$. And this is indeed a Kuratowski pair -- but, alas! it is $\langle\varnothing,\varnothing\rangle$, and $\varnothing\notin\mathbb N$ when we're using Scott's trick.

So with this representation $\mathbb N\cap \mathbb N^2$ is still empty.

---

On the other hand, we might define the natural numbers as $$ \varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{\{\varnothing\}\}, \{\{\{\varnothing\}\}\},\ldots $$
like Zermelo originally did. (Though it is pretty difficult to imagine how this could be extended to a representation of infinite cardinals without obvious seams showing).

In that representation (but still with Kuratowski's pair definition) we have $ n+2 = \langle n, n\rangle$ for all $n$, and therefore $$\mathbb N\cap\mathbb N^2= \{2,3,4,5,\ldots\} $$

Answer (score 5):

If you use this definition:

$$\begin{alignat}{2}
   0 & {} = \{\} && {} = \emptyset,\\
   1 & {} = \{0\} && {} = \{\emptyset\},\\
   2 & {} = \{0,1\} && {} = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\},\\
   3 & {} = \{0,1,2\} && {} = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}
 \end{alignat}$$

then every element of $\mathbb{N}$ is either $\emptyset$ or contains $\emptyset$. This is false for the elements of $\mathbb{N}^2$ using the [standard definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski's_definition) of ordered pair:

$$(a, b) \triangleq \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$$

since $\{a\}\neq\emptyset$ and $\{a, b\}\neq\emptyset$. So $\mathbb{N}\cap\mathbb{N}^2=\emptyset$.

If you use an alternative definition, like $(a, b) \triangleq \{a, \{a, b\}\}$, then we can have $a = b = \emptyset \Rightarrow (a, b) = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset,\emptyset\}\} = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\} = 2 \neq \emptyset$. Under this definition of ordered pair, we have $\mathbb{N}\cap\mathbb{N}^2 \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: What about the definition I gave?

Comment: I actually posted the same argument 15 minutes earlier. Btw, as one sees from what you wrote, it's not true that every element of $\Bbb N$ has $\emptyset$ for an element.

Comment: Do you know that that "alternative definition"  works? (Ie, that it gives $(a,b)=(c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$  and $b=d$?)

Comment: @Wood Thank you for the thoughtful answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No, I'm trusting Wikipedia on this. They give the link to this proof, which I haven't checked: http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/opthreg.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer to this question is $\mathbb{N}\cap\mathbb{N}^2=\varnothing$.

$\mathbb{N}$ is a set of numbers: $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.  $\mathbb{N}^2$ is a Cartesian cross product of elements of $\mathbb{N}$.  That is, an element of $\mathbb{N}^2$ has the form $(a,b)$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$.  An ordered pair $(a,b)$ is defined as $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$.  Since no element of $\mathbb{N}$ takes this form, the intersection must be $\varnothing$.

Comment: Can you provide a more formal proof?

Comment: This amounts to just saying the intersection is empty because it's empty! The point is to _prove_ that no element of $\Bbb N$ has the form $(a,b)$.

Comment: If the elements of the intersected sets aren't the same type of element, then no element can belong to both sets.

Comment: [sigh] Right. Except you have to _define_ "same type" and then _prove_ that $n$ is not the same type as $(a,b)$. (See Wood's answer - there's a reasonable definition of $(a,b)$ where $(0,0)=2$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  I see.  I've added a definition of ordered pair to my answer.

Comment: That's progress. But you're still just proving the intersection iis empty by saying it's empty; you need to use the definition of $(a,b)$ to _prove_ that $n\ne(a,b)$. Now that you've given a definition that's possible, as in the other two answers...

Answer (score -1):

**Note:** No, you absolutely cannot take $$(\forall x)(\forall x^\prime)(\forall y)(\forall y^\prime)\big((x,y) = (x^\prime,y^\prime) \implies x = x^\prime \text{ and } y = y^\prime\big).$$ as the definition of ordered pairs! The above is a property of ordered  pairs, but it does not specify what $(x,y)$ *is*. In fact  there's a *standard* definition of $(x,y)$ in set theory.

**Hint:** If $x$ and $y$ are sets then $(x,y)\ne\emptyset$ and also every element of $(x,y)$ is nonempty.

(Of course the answer depends on the definition of $\Bbb N$.)

Comment: I did not downvote but I also do not understand how to proceed from the hint.

Comment: @simplejack Have you thought about it? If $n\in\Bbb N$ you want to show that $n\ne(j,k)$. If you believe the assertion in the hint it's enough to show that $n=\emptyset$ or $\emptyset\in n$.

Comment: So it is the same idea as the answer by @Wood? I don't see how it can be used with the definitions I added to the question.

Comment: @simplejack Yes,  it's the same idea as the other answer. It's also _correct_, which the other answer is not, quite (it's not true that every $n\in \Bbb N$ has the empty set as an element.

Comment: @simplejack It's  impossible to do this without a definition of $(x,y)$.  There is  no definition of $(x,y)$ in your question.

Comment: Someone explain why the downvotes...